# Unable to reset the focus ordinal bar chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to reset after choosing some of the individual's bar.

**index.html:** (line no. 62)

```
<span>
  <a href="javascript:focus.filterAll(); dc.redrawAll();"  class="reset">reset</a>
</span>
```

This seems not to work. I was able to reset all the graphs pie chart, line chart, etc but not this one.

Those two ordinal graphs are created in `index.js` like this:

```
var focus = new dc.barChart('#focus');
var range = new dc.barChart('#range');
```

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/483fd69328694c6b6125bb43b9f7f8a7

**Update:**
It looks weird now Coz it's showing a single bar and all the bar have got invisible but I want them to be visible (in gray colour) but not clickable.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example replaces the built-in filtering functionality of the bar chart with its own implementation of ordinal selection, because the chart has a linear scale.

The example uses a global variable `focusFilter` to store the current selection. We need to empty this out and we also need to update the dimension filter as the original `filterAll` would do, pulling that code out of the click handler:

```
    focus.applyFilter = function() { // non-standard method
        if(focusFilter.length)
            this.dimension().filterFunction(function(k) {
                return focusFilter.includes(k);
            });
        else this.dimension().filter(null);
    };
    focus.filterAll = function() {
        focusFilter = [];
        this.applyFilter();
    };
```

This will also allow [dc.filterAll()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/global.html#filterAll) to work, for a "reset all" link.

[Fork of your block](https://blockbuilder.org/gordonwoodhull/cd17a8e40ee9af5d881c3eb9b69179df).

For some reason, I could not get the original

```
<a href="javascript:focus.filterAll(); dc.redrawAll()">reset</a>
```

links to work at all in this block, so I replaced them with the equivalent D3 click handlers:

```
    d3.select('#reset-focus').on('click', () => {
      focus.filterAll();
      dc.redrawAll();
    })
    d3.select('#reset-all').on('click', () => {
      dc.filterAll();
      dc.redrawAll();
    })
```

I also updated [the focus ordinal bar example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/focus-ordinal-bar.html). Note that automatic hiding/showing of the reset link doesn't work because the chart still has an irrelevant range filter inside of it.

Comment: is it possible instead of making them not visible I can make them light blue and disable clicking on them. Like for this https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/focus-ordinal-bar.html If I click on below row chart bar say the first one `s` I want those got removed will be in light blue (but not active , click disabled for them)

Comment: Do you mean something like the [compare unfiltered example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/compare-unfiltered.html), where the baseline data is still shown “behind” the filtered data? As you can see, it takes a significant amount of extra work because it’s not something natively supported by dc.js/crossfilter.

Comment: yes I want that. if not that then I want to display all the other but in gray colour. as you can see from my updated screenshot. It's displaying a single bar and all the bar is gone. I want to display  the others graph also but in gray colour instead of reoving them completely.

Comment: Everything is possible. It’s just work. Take a look at the code of that example to see what is entailed - it’s a composite with the unfiltered data displayed in the background. Like the ordinal range/focus, the functionality is not built in (crossfilter only implements the filtering) so you end up implementing basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks will start implementing that.