# Changing colour of bar on selecting and unselecting bar in composite chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/63295ea0a8052716644738d37d390e52

1)

[image]
When I click on focus ordinal bar((c2 of composite chart) it should keep the selected one as red and other as grey but it doesn't.

2)

[image]

When I click on pie chart I get red bars along with unfiltered bar(grey). Here clicking on red bar should filter other graphs it's doing that as you can see my table and pie chart is getting updated but When I click on gray bar data is also getting filtered but for pie chart it just add grey slices.

**Line no. 284-324:**

```
chart_11.fadeDeselectedArea = function (brushSelection) {
    var _chart = this;
    var bars = _chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('rect.bar');
    if (chart_11Filter.length) {
        bars.classed(dc.constants.SELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
            return chart_11Filter.includes(d.data.key);
        });
        bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, function (d) {
            return !chart_11Filter.includes(d.data.key);
        });
    } else {
        bars.classed(dc.constants.SELECTED_CLASS, false);
        bars.classed(dc.constants.DESELECTED_CLASS, false);
    }
};
chart_11.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click.ordinal-select', function(d) {
        var i = chart_11Filter.indexOf(d.data.key);
        if(i >= 0)
            chart_11Filter.splice(i, 1);
        else
            chart_11Filter.push(d.data.key);
        chart.applyFilter();
        chart.redrawGroup();
    });
});
```

If I use the above code then I get these things So I can think of these solutions.
I can change the colour of c2 bar on clicking by using the above code and applying it to c2.
also for the second graph I can use css to disable on clicking them or I 
can make the filter to return none.

But when I tried the above solutions It didn't work. Problems were still the same.

If I make this function applicable only for c2 by replacing chart_11 with c2:

```
chart_11.fadeDeselectedArea = function (brushSelection) {
.
.
.
.
chart_11.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
.
.
.
```

I get this:

[image]

### Edit:

```
    chart_11.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click', null);
```

If I add this I will be able to disable clicking all bar. I have to make it only for C1.

```
    chart_11.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        // chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click', null);
        chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click.ordinal-select', function(d) {
```

In this function my 2nd issue can be solved I guess. This function has to be customized. Accessing the child C2 and select its rect.bar and filter. 
But unable to write the code for it.

Comment: Sorry for asking lot of questions. The original dashboard was built using power bi consisting of 4-5 pages with so many graphs. It was on trial period then. So now I have to create all the graphs from scratch, and make it to look similar to the power bi dashboard. I am efficient in python and visualization with python libraries. So facing lot of challenges implementing a single graph using dc.js. Not so good with javascript. If I got the examples I am able to write the functions in javscript but if not I get struck.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I learn a lot from helping people with dc.js, and it's especially fun when I get to work with someone who's a good coder and we expand the bounds of what dc.js can do.

Comment: I took a quick look - don't have time to dig into the code right now. I think you want to modify `c1` and `c2` not the composite that holds them? The child charts work just like they always did, the composite chart just puts one in front of the other and takes chart of common elements like axes and brushes.

Comment: yes I want to add selection and deslection the bar from c2 only. I want c1 to be on background with no interactivity. and also for creating a click event I have to modify to make it work for c2.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood - it looks like your code is trying to modify `chart_11` instead, which is the composite parent, when it should modify `c2`?

Comment: I don't know but somehow reset issue has been fixed. I have no clue what changes I made to  solve undefined for domain and selectAll peoblem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211888/discussion-between-pygirl-and-gordon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is getting to be a very hacky solution, combining two already hacky customizations of dc.js.

However, you weren't very far off; it is just a matter of restricting behaviors to `c2` and cleaning out some irrelevant code.

I removed `hide_second_chart` because that's not necessary here, and removed the `filterHandler` for the same reason.

As you pointed out, `fadeDeselectedArea` has to be overridden on the parent; for some reason it doesn't fire on the children.

But this selection was empty, so nothing happened:

```
        var bars = _chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('rect.bar');
```

I changed it to

```
        var bars = c2.selectAll('rect.bar');
```

Also, the click handler should be specific to the second child, so this

```
    chart_11.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click.ordinal-select', function(d) {
```

becomes

```
    c2.on('pretransition.click-handler', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('.sub._1 rect.bar').on('click.ordinal-select', function(d) {
```

`.sub._1` is CSS that will select only the second child chart.

We can use similar CSS to disable hover behaviors on the first child chart:

```
  .dc-chart .sub._0 rect.bar:hover {
      fill-opacity: 1;
  }

  .dc-chart .sub._0 rect.bar {
      cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Enable `filterAll`, as discussed in [Unable to reset the focus ordinal bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183084/unable-to-reset-the-focus-ordinal-bar-chart):

```
    chart_11.filterAll = function() {
        chart_11Filter = [];
        chart_11.filter(null);
    };
```

Finally, it is confusing if the unfiltered chart is not the same color as deselected bars, so we change `grey` to `#ccc`:

```
  .colors('#ccc')
```

[image: working selection screenshot]

[Working fork of your block](https://blockbuilder.org/gordonwoodhull/e3857114f8facc1c54e28935e2494d01).

Hopefully the range/focus part still works, because otherwise this is making things much more complicated than they need to be!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I thought to disable clicking on grey bar chart like this `chart_11.<child graph>` or `selectAll('rect.bar <having fill=grey>')` tag like this. I didn't know I can select directly from child graph.